# pyqt update qgraphicsscene with mousewheelevent output

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a set of images that I want to be able to scroll through. The below code works for me on Mac, such that I can scroll on the visible widget. Printing "count" results in a visible rising or lowering number in the python output. However, I wish to use "count" to update the image and I am kinda stuck on how.

The main question is: How can I use the constantly varying variable "count" from my mousewheel function, and use it to update the image shown in the DCMViewer? I expect some kind of signal to work, but haven't got it working and I'm stuck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
class DCMViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DCMViewer, self).__init__()

        # Create a QGraphicsScene
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()

        # Provide image in normalized double format
        image = np.double(dcmIm)
        image *= 255.0 / image.max()
        image = QPixmap.fromImage(qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(image))
        image = QGraphicsPixmapItem(image)

        # Add the image to the QGraphicsScene window
        self.scene.addItem(image)

        # Initiate the scene
        self.setScene(self.scene)

    # Create a mousewheelevent to scroll through images
    def wheelEvent(self, QWheelEvent):
        super(DCMViewer, self).wheelEvent(QWheelEvent)
        global count
        wheelcounter = QWheelEvent.angleDelta()
        if wheelcounter.y() / 120 == -1:
            count += 1
            if count >= 21:
                count = 21
        elif wheelcounter.y() / 120 == 1:
            count -= 1
            if count <= 0:
                count = 0

class Mainwidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainwidget, self).__init__()

        # self.initUI()
        image_viewer = DCMViewer()
        self.setCentralWidget(image_viewer)
        self.showFullScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Mainwidget()
    win.showFullScreen()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I do not understand anything, what do you mean by *I wish to use "count" to update the image*? What do you want to update?

Comment: Do you want to zoom?

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't want to zoom. I want to use the "count" variable to scroll through the images.

Comment: to understand you better, let's say that count is 5, what should happen? Where should you go?

Comment: I see that you have placed only one image, to which images do you refer?

Comment: My count starts at 0 and when scrolling should go up by one. 0 would be the first image of the data set and (in this case) 21 the last. For each increase or decrease of count, the corresponding image from the dataset should be shown in the graphics widget. If count = 5, the sixth image should be shown, etc.

Comment: and in what position are the images. Are all the images in the same position or different positions?

Comment: Are the images on top of each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to make an item visible, the first task we must do is to identify it, for that we could establish an id for each item. We use the `setData()` and `data()` method, then we use the `fitInView()` method to scale the window to the item, this does not make the item totally visible because if there is another item on it we will get an unwanted output, for that we use `setZValue()`, the higher the value of Z will be on top of another item, your code will not provide an example that can be tested correctly so create my own example:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class DCMViewer(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DCMViewer, self).__init__()
        self.currentId = 0
        self.maxId = 0
        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        directory = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.PicturesLocation)
        it = QDirIterator(directory, QDir.Files)

        while it.hasNext():
            pixmap = QPixmap(it.next())
            item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
            item.setData(0, self.maxId)
            self.scene().addItem(item)
            self.maxId += 1

    def scrollToItem(self, id):
        for item in self.scene().items():
            if item.data(0) == id:
                item.setZValue(1)
                self.fitInView(item)
            else:
                item.setZValue(0)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        wheelcounter = event.angleDelta()
        if wheelcounter.y() / 120 == -1:
            self.currentId += 1
            if self.currentId > self.maxId:
                self.currentId = self.maxId -1
        elif wheelcounter.y() / 120 == 1:
            self.currentId -= 1
            if self.currentId <= 0:
                self.currentId = 0
        self.scrollToItem(self.currentId)


class Mainwidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mainwidget, self).__init__()
        image_viewer = DCMViewer()
        self.setCentralWidget(image_viewer)
        self.showFullScreen()
        image_viewer.scrollToItem(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Mainwidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And thanks for the incredibly fast reaction! This pretty much worked for my application. I had just one question. I do not fully understand the scrollToItem function. Could you elaborate on what happens there?